# Userform Dropdown list populating incorrectly when the value is changed

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform that has two dropdown lists. The first one has three options and the second one will populate different options depending on which of the three options you chose first. When testing the dropdown lists, everything works fine the FIRST TIME. But, once you try to change the value on the first dropdown list, you will see it has more than 12 options (the initial 3 options duplicated over and over again). None of the options will populate the second dropdown list again.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()

With ComboBox1
.AddItem "Option 1"
.AddItem "Option 2"
.AddItem "Option 3"
End With

End Sub

-------------------------------------------------------------------

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim index As Integer
index = ComboBox1.ListIndex

ComboBox2.Clear

Select Case index
Case Is = 0
    With ComboBox2
        .AddItem "Option 1.1"
        .AddItem "Option 1.2"
        .AddItem "Option 1.3"
    End With
Case Is = 1
    With ComboBox2
        .AddItem "Option 2.1"
        .AddItem "Option 2.2"
        .AddItem "Option 2.3"
        .AddItem "Option 2.4"
        .AddItem "Option 2.5"
    End With
Case Is = 2
    With ComboBox2
        .AddItem "Option 3.1"
        .AddItem "Option 3.2"
    End With
End Select

End Sub
```

I want to be able to change the first dropdown list many times without the code breaking. So, in case you change your mind about option 1, you can always go back and change it to option 2, and get the list for option 2 correctly.

Comment: You are adding and adding and adding items to ComboBox1 each time you click the dropdown button. You might just want to add items on userform initialize to be honest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to eleborate on my comment:

Change:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_DropButtonClick()
```

Into:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
```

Because right now you are adding items to your `ComboBox1` each time you click the dropdown button. Obviously creating a larger index causing your second ComboBox to fail adding items. Somewhat strange you didn't notice this practice because you applied the `ComboBox2.Clear` code too.

Comment: Its somewhat strange because i grabbed this code from the internet and modified it to my needs. Only people like you would notice, not people like me. Thank you for the answer. :)